# Fourier transform of this oddly worded function

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

A function is equal to zero outside a unit area square centered at
(0,0) and inside a central quarter-unit area square similarly oriented.
Elsewhere the function is equal to unity. I am trying to find the formula of
the function and its Fourier Transform. Now, I have two issues with the wording of this problem. Firstly, is a "quarter-unit area square" a square with side lengths $\frac{1}{2}$ (which gives one fourth the area) or side lengths $\frac{1}{4}.$ Secondly, what does it mean for a function to be equal to unity? I can't seem to find a definition anywhere on the web or in the reference manual that stated this function. Anyways, making assumptions of side length $\frac{1}{2}$ and unity $= 1$, I've got the following function:

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & \text{if} \;\frac{1}{2} \leq max(|x|,|y|) \leq 1 \\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

Now, if all that is correct, how do I find the Fourier transform of this?

Comment: You got the function right. For the Fourier transform, it's easier to write $f$ as the difference of two functions: One is unity inside the bigger square, the other is unity inside the smaller square. Compute the Fourier transform of both (very similar calculations) and subtract.

Comment: For one of the fourier transforms, I am familiar with the fact that the Fourier transform of $$
f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & \text{if} \; |x| > 1\\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$ is $$
F(w) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{2sin(w)}{w} & \text{if} \; w \neq 0 \\
       2 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$ but how do I go about computing the transform of the function you have shown me.